# Custom validation in yii2 while merging two public variables

Tags: php, validation, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

Actually I'm working on ajax validation in `Yii 2`. I am sending two public variables data into a column in DB. while loading a post values. How to validate custom onto that field.

My Code:

```php
public $prefix;
public $mobile;
$model->phone = Yii::$app->request->post('prefix') . '' . Yii::$app->request->post('mobile');
```

and I want this

```php
['phone, 'unique']
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Code which you pasted is not enough, it's just uncategorized scraps. Paste here full controller/model code, otherwise we can't help you.

Answer (score 0):

Add the rule to the class definition of the model, validate and do with the validation result what you want. E.g. return true when validated true or the error message when validated false.

```
class YourModel extends ActiveRecord {
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            ['phone', 'unique'],
        ];
    }
}

$model->validate();
```

If you have more validation rules you can get the result for the phone attribute using `$model->getErrors('phone')`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to merge both variables before calling validate function on model.
Your controller action code should be like below :

```
$model->phone=model->prefix.$model->mobile;
$model->validate();
//rest of code
```